# Only allow users to see files they previously uploaded in Assets

Tags: add-on, assets, uploads, safecracker-file

With the new html upload form would it be possible to add files like using safecracker file upload?

I want members to be able to upload images/files (ideally with assets) and then they can only see what they have uploaded and not the directory of files. Is this possible?

Comment: It'd be very nice if this were possible.

Comment: It is possible, with an easy hack. See my answer to a similar question here: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/7666/safecracker-assets-file-browser-showing-only-logged-in-members-assets/9450#9450

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with Assets: Assets does not track who uploaded a file, so this kind of association is not there.

Comment: I must have read too much into the feature "give your files a name" on http://pixelandtonic.com/assets it mentions author, would be a nice feature though

Comment: Ah, yes - that is indicative of the credit / author in the Metadata for the file.  Make sense?