# SafeCracker + Assets: Restrict file browser to display logged-in member's files only.

Tags: assets, safecracker, members, login

Is there a way to configure the Assets file browser in a SafeCracker form to only show assets for the currently logged-in member?

Answer (score 2):

Assets 2.1 is easily hackable, here's what you can do to restrict the file browser to the currently logged-in member's (standard ExpressionEngine) assets only:

First, add a 'member_id' column to the assets_files table:

```
ALTER TABLE  `exp_assets_files` ADD  `member_id` INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NULL
```

Modify assets/sources/base_source.php (line 605) to add the member_id to the db table:

```
'file_name' => $filename,
'member_id' => $this->EE->session->userdata('member_id'), // Add 'member_id' to database
'kind' => Assets_helper::get_kind($filename)
```

Finally, modify assets/libraries/assets_lib.php (line 712) to limit the display of files to the currently logged in member only:

Change this existing line:

```
$this->EE->db->where_in('exp_assets_files.folder_id', $full_folder_list);
```

To this:

```
$this->EE->db->where_in('exp_assets_files.folder_id', $full_folder_list)->where('member_id', $this->EE->session->userdata('member_id'));
```

Comment: I wonder if there are hooks available that would allow this to be implemented via another addon...

Answer (score 1):

No, not yet, sorry Roger. We do have something planned for that, but I can't make any promises regarding ETA.