# Assets upload with channel form to sub folder with userid

Tags: assets, safecracker

I´m trying to make users upload files to a folder in assets that contains only user files. But i want them to, when they open to select files and upload files, to have a folder with the memberid as folder name. And that this folder is the base for the user, so that they can make subfolder. To make subfolders is not a crucial function.

I know assets don't have this functionality and that i have to hack it to make it work until assets get this functionality of some kind.
I have tried to use channel images for this, but channel form didn't like that one bit. i have tried the [member_id on files fix](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/7666/safecracker-assets-restrict-file-browser-to-display-logged-in-members-files?rq=1) but that doesn't work with assets 2.4.

I use zoo visitor for users, so i can make and delete folders when a user is made and deleted.
The user groups that are going to use this dont have access to the controlpanel, only the channel forms, thats why i think a hack of some kind may work.

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is exactly?

Comment: I want users to use a subfolder in assets that becomes their base folder, so they only upload and select files from that folder. They should only have access to their own files, thats why i tried the member_id on files fix. Was that any clearer? :)

Comment: Yes, but what's the question? Are you asking for the code required in order to hack Assets to do this? Seems like a pretty large scope for a question.

Comment: ah sorry, yeah some code would have been good, but some concept code is as good. I'm trying to understand more how it works and how to manipulate it.
From the member_id on files fix solution they just include a parameter in the sql-call. I guess that is something for this solution too. I just cant see the solution here...